# planning between 2 models

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I yet have a problem with my planning. My frist model is `Revision` with as informations following:

The date_revision_start on `12/09/2019` to `14/09/2019` then hour_start & hour_end from `07:00` to `09:00` and the bike `000001`.

Below, I have no problem...

[image]

Now, in my model `Training` if I want to enter a training on `14/09/2019` from `10:00` to `12:00` for the bike `000001`.

I have an error message ?? Normally, the recording is correct...

[image]

[image]

Do you have an idea for better compare my `hour_start` &  `hour_end`?

```
$date_seance = $request->get('date_seance'); 
$hour_start = $request->get('hour_start'); 
$hour_end = $request->get('hour_end'); 
$fk_motorbike = $request->get('fk_motorbike');
$fk_student = $request->get('fk_student');
$fk_former = $request->get('fk_former');
$fk_typeseance = $request->get('fk_typeseance');

$conflictTraining = Training::where('fk_motorbike', $request->get('fk_motorbike'))  
        ->whereDate('date_seance', "=" , $date_seance)  
        ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $request->get('hour_start')) 
        ->where('hour_end', ">=" , $request->get('hour_end'))
        ->where('fk_former', $request->get('fk_former'))
        ->first();  

$conflictRevision = Revision::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)
            ->whereDate('date_revision_start', "<=" , $date_seance)
            ->whereDate('date_revision_end', ">=", $date_seance)
            ->first();

$conflictRevision1 = Revision::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)
            ->whereDate('date_revision_start', "<=" , $date_seance)
            ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $request->get('hour_start'))  
            ->where('hour_end', ">=" , $request->get('hour_end'))
            ->first();

$conflictRevision2 = Revision::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)
            ->whereDate('date_revision_end', "<=" , $date_seance)
            ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $request->get('hour_start'))  
            ->where('hour_end', ">=" , $request->get('hour_end'))
            ->first();

$conflictFormer = Training::where('fk_former', $fk_former)  
            ->whereDate('date_seance', "=" , $date_seance)  
            ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $request->get('hour_start')) 
            ->where('hour_end', ">=" , $request->get('hour_end'))
            ->first();  

$conflictMotorbike = Training::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)  
            ->whereDate('date_seance', "=" , $date_seance)  
            ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $request->get('hour_start')) 
            ->where('hour_end', ">=" , $request->get('hour_end'))
            ->first();
```

Thank you for your help and your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you have a conflict error message that the motorbike is in revision is that you are comparing against **days only** in your first `$conflictRevision` query.  There is no time there in that first query, so it matches against the **day** only for any given hour -- thus ALL hours of the day will fail / be in conflict.

You have three queries that are doing similar things:

```
$conflictRevision = Revision::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)
        ->whereDate('date_revision_start', "<=" , $date_seance)
        ->whereDate('date_revision_end', ">=", $date_seance)
        ->first();

$conflictRevision1 = Revision::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)
        ->whereDate('date_revision_start', "<=" , $date_seance)
        ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $request->get('hour_start'))  
        ->where('hour_end', ">=" , $request->get('hour_end'))
        ->first();

$conflictRevision2 = Revision::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)
        ->whereDate('date_revision_end', "<=" , $date_seance) 
        ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $request->get('hour_start'))  
        ->where('hour_end', ">=" , $request->get('hour_end'))
        ->first();
```

The first query above is the one that is causing you the unwanted error message.  Remove the `$conflictRevision` query because it will match to **any** time.  Remove the `$conflictRevision2` query because it is a duplicate of the one above it.  However, you will need to add the end date to the `$conflictRevision`, or it will never work.  You have an open-ended end or start date using it as you have it above.  Using conflict1 the way you have it, *everything* in your database with a revision starting before the `$date_seance` will conflict since there is no end date for that query):

```
$conflictRevision1 = Revision::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)
    ->whereDate('date_revision_start', "<=" , $date_seance)
    ->whereDate('date_revision_end', ">=" , $date_seance) // <--Note I changed the operator
    ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $request->get('hour_start'))  
    ->where('hour_end', ">=" , $request->get('hour_end'))
    ->first();
```

And... the motorbike in revision issue should be solved.